# Python - How do you refer to a list's items (that are variables) without referring to their value

Tags: python, list

okay so im trying to create a blackjack game where the picture of a card is used, i have everything working nicely however ive decided to go down another way of displaying the cards as it would be more efficient. i have a list for all the cards i need and would like to refer to the variable names inside of it, not the values of the variables. To help clarify, heres some of my code:

```
Jack = 10
Queen = 10
King = 10
Ace = 11    
cards = [ACE, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King]

firstcard = cards[random.randrange(1,14)]
seccard = cards[random.randrange(1,14)]
total = firstcard + seccard
```

however the problem with this is it doesnt differentiate between the Jack, the queen or the king. id like to use an if statement that would go along the lines of the following:

```
if firstcard = cards[Jack]:
    (code for using the appropriate image)
```

again, the problem here is that the computer always sees through the index name and looks at what the variable is equal to (in this case 10). id like to know if theres a way of directly referring to the variable name being selected rather than the variable's value. i have already got my card images working nicely this is simply a case of selecting them now.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should have a look at Dictionary in python. That will let you provide different index values and then you can get the corresponding value for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ultimately want to use a dictionary here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be sure to note the difference between `=` and `==` in your code. The former `a = b` will set `a` as equal to `b`. The latter `a == b` won't change `a` or `b`, and will return True if they are the same, or False if they are not.

As for how to differentiate face cards from the number 10, and each other, it might be helpful to store the cards as strings, and use a dictionary to extract the numbers from each card value.

```
# store the cards as strings
cards = ["Ace", "2", "3", ..., "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
# use a dictionary to store the value of each string
values_of_cards = {"Ace": 1, "2": 2, ..., "10": 10, "Jack": 10, "Queen": 10, "King": 10}
# same code to find the first and second card, only they're strings now
first_card = cards[random.randomrange(1, 14)]
second_card = cards[random.randomrange(1, 14)]
# slight change on how you calculate the values of the cards
total = values_of_cards[first_card] + values_of_cards[second_card]
# figuring out what card you have is now super easy -- just make sure to use == instead of =
if first_card == "Jack":
    # code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You're refering to your variables by value and since Jack, Queen, King and 10 have a value of 10 of course they appear the same to the Python interpreter.

If you want to have the same value but different representation you need to use a bit more complex structure. dict is probably the simplest to understand:

```
cards = {
    "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4, "five": 5, "six": 6, "seven": 7, "eight": 8, "nine": 9,
    "ten": 10, "jack": 10, "queen": 10, "king": 10, "ace": 11
}
card_names = cards.keys()

# you can now create shortcuts like ACE = "ace" if you don't want to type string keys

# to generate the cards
first_card = random.choice(card_names)
second_card = random.choice(card_names)

# to get their total value
total = cards[first_card] + cards[second_card]

# and to check the card:
if first_card == "jack":
    print("It's a Jack!")
```

However, this would look far more elegant (and in certain cases more performant) if you were to just do it OOP way.